# Atom editor - npm package

Tags: atom-editor

Does anyone know how can i run the scripts of package.json file - from the editor?
Is there any Atom package for this operation?
I have already tried to search for a package on atom.io/packages page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the npm-plus package:

https://atom.io/packages/npm-plus